# Requiring public IP address for kafka running on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-kafka

We have kafka and zookeeper installed on a single AWS EC2 instance. We have kafka producers and consumers running on separate ec2 instances which are on the same VPC and have the same security group as that of kafka instance. In the producer or consumer config we are using the internal IP address of the kafka server to connect to it.

But we have noticed that we need to mention the public IP address of the EC2 server as advertised.listeners for letting the producers and consumers connect to the Kafka server:

```
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://PUBLIC_IP:9092
```

Also we have to whitelist the public ip addresses and open traffic on 9092 port of each of our ec2 servers running producers and consumers.

We want the traffic to flow using internal IP addresses. Is there a way we need not whitelist the public ip addresses and open traffic on 9092 port for each one of our servers running producer or consumer?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to open access to all for either one of your servers, I would recommend adding a proper high performance web server like nginx or Apache HTTPD in front of your applications' servers acting as a reverse proxy. This way you could also add SSL encryption and your server stays on a private network while only the web server would be exposed. It’s very easy and you can find many tutorials on how to set it up. Like this one: http://webapp.org.ua/sysadmin/setting-up-nginx-ssl-reverse-proxy-for-tomcat/

Answer (score 0):

Because of the variable nature of the ecosystem that kafka may need to work in, it only makes sense that you are explicit in declaring the locations which kafka can use. The only way to guarantee that external parts of any system can be reached via an ip address is to ensure that you are using external ip addresses.